# How to install latex beamer color theme

Tags: latex, beamer

I would like to use the owl color theme (https://github.com/rchurchley/beamercolortheme-owl) in my LaTeX beamer presentation.  I am new to both LaTeX and beamer and have a new Miktex installation. I am on Windows 7.

I am trying to follow the instructions here: https://github.com/rchurchley/beamercolortheme-owl/blob/master/README.md

When I try to compile `beamercolorthemeowl.ins` in TexStudio, I get an error: Could not start Default Complier:PdfLaTeX: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "beamercolorthemeowl".tex.

I can compile other files in TexStudio.  That is my beamer presentation compiles with the default theme.

When I try to compile `beamercolorthemeowl.ins` in TeXworks, I get a message in the 'Console output' that says:

> )
>
> Generating file(s) ./beamercolorthemeowl.sty  ! Cannot find file
>   beamercolorthemeowl.dtx. \readsource ...ot find file \uptospace #1
>   \qStop }
>                                                     \else \processedLines \z@ ... l.41           }
>                    ?

and the program is just busy for ages and ages and nothing happens.

The file `beamercolorthemeowl.dtx` is sitting in the same directory as `beamercolorthemeowl.ins`, so I don't understand why it cannot find it.

Any suggestions on what to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texstudio tries to be clever and adds some incorrect file type. Running `latex beamercolorthemeowl.ins` directly will generate the following file `beamercolorthemeowl.sty`:

```
%%
%% This is file `beamercolorthemeowl.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% beamercolorthemeowl.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Copyright 2016 Ross Churchley. Contributions to this package are welcome at
%% 
%%     https://github.com/rchurchley/beamercolortheme-owl
%% 
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions of
%% the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3 of this license
%% or (at your option) any later version. The latest version of this
%% license is in:
%% 
%%     http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% 
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX version
%% 2005/12/01 or later.
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2005/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{beamercolorthemeowl}
    [2016/03/15 v0.1.1 A visible colour theme for Beamer presentations]
  \RequirePackage{etoolbox}
  \newtoggle{snowy}
  \newtoggle{cautious}
  \@ifclassloaded{beamer}{
    \DeclareOptionBeamer{snowy}{\toggletrue{snowy}}
    \DeclareOptionBeamer{cautious}{\toggletrue{cautious}}
    \ProcessOptionsBeamer
  }{}
  \@ifclassloaded{beamer}{
    \iftoggle{snowy}{
      \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black, bg=white}
    }{
      \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white, bg=black}
    }
  }{}
  \RequirePackage{xcolor}
  \definecolor{OwlRed}{RGB}{    255,  92, 168}
  \definecolor{OwlGreen}{RGB}{   90, 168,   0}
  \definecolor{OwlBlue}{RGB}{     0, 152, 233}
  \definecolor{OwlYellow}{RGB}{ 242, 147,  24}
  \colorlet{OwlViolet}{OwlRed!50!OwlBlue}
  \colorlet{OwlBrown}{OwlRed!50!OwlGreen}
  \colorlet{OwlOrange}{OwlRed!50!OwlYellow}
  \colorlet{OwlCyan}{OwlGreen!50!OwlBlue}
\iftoggle{cautious}{}{
  \colorlet{red}{OwlRed}
  \colorlet{green}{OwlGreen}
  \colorlet{blue}{OwlBlue}
  \colorlet{yellow}{OwlYellow}
  \colorlet{violet}{OwlViolet}
  \colorlet{brown}{OwlBrown}
  \colorlet{orange}{OwlOrange}
  \colorlet{cyan}{OwlCyan}
}
  \@ifclassloaded{beamer}{
    \setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{
      fg=OwlRed
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{example text}{
      fg=OwlGreen
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{title}{
      use=normal text,
      fg=normal text.fg
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{title in sidebar}{
      use=normal text,
      fg=normal text.fg
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{
      use=normal text,
      parent=normal text.fg
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{author}{
      use=normal text,
      parent=normal text.fg
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{date}{
      use=normal text,
      parent=normal text.fg
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{institute}{
      use=normal text,
      parent=normal text.fg
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{structure}{
      use=normal text,
      fg=normal text.fg!50!normal text.bg
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{
      use=normal text,
      fg=normal text.fg!90!normal text.bg,
      bg=normal text.bg!90!normal text.fg
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{
      use=normal text,
      fg=alerted text.fg!75!normal text.bg,
      bg=normal text.bg!90!normal text.fg
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{
      use=normal text,
      fg=example text.fg!75!normal text.bg,
      bg=normal text.bg!90!normal text.fg
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{
      use=normal text,
      fg=normal text.fg!75!normal text.bg,
      bg=normal text.bg!90!normal text.fg
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{sidebar}{
      use=normal text,
      fg=normal text.fg!80!normal text.bg,
      bg=normal text.bg!80!normal text.fg
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar primary}{
      use=palette primary,
      parent=palette primary
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar secondary}{
      use=palette primary,
      parent=palette primary
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar tertiary}{
      use=palette quaternary,
      parent=palette quaternary
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar quaternary}{
      use=palette quaternary,
      parent=palette quaternary
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{
      use=palette primary,
      parent=palette primary
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{block title}{
      use=normal text,
      fg=normal text.fg,
      bg=
    }
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{
      bg=
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{block title alerted}{%
        use={block title, alerted text},
        fg=alerted text.fg,
        bg=block title.bg
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{block title example}{%
        use={block title, example text},
        fg=example text.fg,
        bg=block title.bg
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{block body alerted}{
      use=block body,
      parent=block body
    }
    \setbeamercolor*{block body example}{
      use=block body,
      parent=block body
    }
    \def\beamer@themerounded@shadow{false}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  }{}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `beamercolorthemeowl.sty'.
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, that's great.  For people like me who aren't particularly computer savvy, to 'run directly' in a windows system: open the command prompt >> navigate to the relevant directory (cd to change directory) >> at the command prompt type: latex beamercolorthemeowl.ins.  As the French would say, voila!